# Where to Start: Javascript, NodeJS - plus the universe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, node.js, mongodb

[edit: to clarify] (edit ends at [/edit])

I am not asking for the "best" answer. I am not asking for a "good" answer. I am asking for an answer that fulfills the parameters of the question. The question is this: "Does there exist a learning resource that describes a means of implementing a solution to the problem described?" I don't care if the solution involves bubblegum or duct tape. Is there a way to achieve the goal that is described in a single source that does not require obsolete resources, deprecated libraries, or redacted documents, and, if so, where can I access it, for money or otherwise?

I don't CARE if you LIKE the solution. Does it apply to the problem or not?

[/edit]

I am an HVAC technician. I tinker with coding as a way to relax.

I realize this question has been asked. The problem with answers like "Use Google - you will find lots of information" is that Google puts this website in its top 3 links when you do the search, so it's highly likely that the person asking got her by searching Google for information, and this was one of the sites they suggested. The question has been asked, kinda, and answered, kinda, and yet here I am.

I work for a very small company. The boss sits in the office, the employees work in the field driving from jobsite to jobsite. The boss is braindead as far as efficiently managing workflow and forgets the status of a given job 3 seconds after you tell him the job is completed. I am tired of getting called at 8PM on a Friday night to find out if the job I completed and called in at 10AM on Thursday has been visited. I want to write a web application so we can input via our smartphones the status of a job as the status changes, and the boss can see, at a glance, what he would otherwise call us for.

I have programming experience in Scheme, Lisp, and C/C++, but I know this project is going to take me into entirely new territory.

My research so far indicates I need a programming environment that supports JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and a backend platform/server (NodeJS). WebStorm fits the bill. nice. Then the research tree goes all sideways. AngularJS, JQuery, MongoDB, AJAX, SQLvNoSQL, mommasKnickers, catHair and Potbelly.

Ended that with a joke. You see it?

The problem I am running into is this: I have bought four books, each of which tells me to install obsoleted versions of packages, some of which are no longer available. I have pursued tutorials on the web that get you to step 5 then say you need to install yet another framework and learn it before you can proceed to step 6, providing no support on "learning it". I am suddenly faced with the task of learning Jade and figuring out how to access my server database from within it while not yet having selected a database to serve the backend because three were suggested in the book, even though one of them has obsoleted their support for 32-bit architecture systems and another can't compile on Windows machines.

I am not stupid. I built a fully functional forum framework in CMUCL, complete with authentication, image uploads, etc - several (10+) years ago. I am very good at learning from books. I am very good at extracting the required information from websites. I am suddenly being offered so many options that I can spend an hour at a time researching each one just to dismiss it, and I'm getting very angry at the whole thing.

I want to write a web application that people can access via the browser in their smartphones. I want it to be served by a computer running Windows10 (I will handle the DNS lookups and such). This is also the development computer. The application will serve up to 10 employees (4 at present) who check in maybe 4 times in a 10 hour day (very small bandwidth load, very small data set). The boss will type in jobs and dispatch them to employees; the employees will update the status of the jobs via their web browser. The boss will not need to call me at 8pm on a Friday night. I can work out the coding logic for the idea. I can implement the forms just fine and the backend processing in terms of organizing the data.

JavaScript, HTML, CSS, NodeJS (OK) Express, JQuery, AngularJS (OK... kinda) JSON, AJAX, Jade, MongoDB (which no longer supports 32-bit architecture systems), Redis... Or just go with Visual Studio, C#, SQL server? (Do I need to pay money for that?) or maybe Cloud9 and...

Here is the question: Does there exist a tutorial/college class/book/learning resource that puts all of the necessary components together so a person can have a list of the, say, 12 frameworks and 5 languages they need to learn in order to implement this kind of application? Or is it just a matter of studying every language, library, framework and plugin one at a time until you find a set that works for you?

Comment: Just wanted to add that the smartphones involved are of different architectures and different providers. An iPhone on USCellular, a Galaxy on AT&T, etc., so writing a native phone app is not my ideal solution.

Comment: I really like Codecademy.Com.  You can go a long ways without paying for anything. Some like Treehouse, or Udemy courses. I suggest learning HTML, CSS, SQL PHP and JavaScript. Branch out from there. But do check out my first suggestion. About smartphones you might want to learn about Android or Bootstrap. Just learn the core languages and experiment a bit until you find what works.

Comment: Thank you. I will examine each of your suggestions in the order provided. I was not asking for the "right" answer; I was asking for ANY answer, and you provided three, it looks like. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice. This question is now on Hold because it is primarily "opinion based". Asking if there exists any resource that is up to date that addresses the question is opinion-based? We need to find a universal definition of the word 'opinion".

Comment: Anything that event hints at asking how to sort through all the language and framework choices for both front-end and back-end simply cannot be answered without a lot of opinion because there was no objective set of requirements proposed that could lead to a recommendation that was not based on opinion.  That ends up making those types of questions just not very good for this venue and people here are quick to swat them away when they come.  I often try first to find as non-opinion-as-possible a way to answer, but others do not take that approach and instead vote to close.

Comment: I will edit my question to clarify that I am not asking for a "best' solution, or even a "good" solution, but a solution that meets the empirical requirements of the actual question asked. Thank you.

Comment: Just a question: What will all of those people who spend their time flagging questions as unanswerable do when people stop asking questions? Walk the dog? Do the dishes? Spend time with their wives? "Oh, you didn't format your question correctly - we need to block you" What happens when people realize that asking a question gets them blocked and decide to go elsewhere? You have invested much to get Google to put you at the top of their search list, then !@#%-!@#& the people who click on the links. Is there nobody in charge watching, deciding what your @#$% purpose is?

Comment: @HippoPotamus - This place is largely moderated by the community via upvotes, downvotes, closevotes, etc...  There are official moderators, but it appears that most of the work is done by the community. It generally works.  It is far from perfect though and one of the larger perfections (IMO) is around this very topic.  Questions that could get very good and useful answers are closed because others think the question asks for too much opinion and they vote to close.  Over time, you will learn how to phrase to avoid this issue and dealing with a closed question is part of how you learn.

Comment: @HippoPotamus - Once your question is closed, it rarely does any good to edit it to try to get it reopened.  It pretty much just doesn't happen.  Once it's closed people just don't really see it any more.  So, if you really want to reask a question about this that won't get closed for these reasons, then you can post a new question phrased differently.  FYI, your question also has major issues about being "too broad" too.  You need to ask much more specific questions here.  Answers should be possible in a few paragraphs and/or a little code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little hard to pin point an answer to this question as it's fairly broad, but I'll do the best I can.

First off, I'm not sure why you think you need 12 frameworks and 5 languages.  You simply don't.  There are tons of things to choose from, but your choices fall into a few simple categories and you don't need to evaluate everything to make a choice.  You just need to find a reasonable choice that fits your experience and learning desire.  There are thousands of "reasonable" choices that will work here.

Here are the basic categories of tech you need:

1. **Front-end language.** If it's a browser-based app, that will be Javascript since that's what runs in the browser.  If it's a smartphone app, then it could be a wide variety of things, but native to Android is Java and native to Apple is Objective C.  I'd suggest that you first build a browser-based application so you're just using Javascript, HTML and CSS on the front-end.  You can always expand later to build a native smartphone app if you want.
2. **Front-end Framework.**  You don't have to have a front-end framework, but you will probably find it handy to have one.  There are many "right" choices.  I'd suggest jQuery or Angular.  Angular will dictate a style of organizing your front-end code, jQuery will not.  Angular will do more frameworky stuff for you at the cost of having to learn more in order to take advantage.
3. **Back-end Language.**  The choices here are limitless (C#, Java, Javascript, Python, PHP, Ruby, etc...).  I'd personally recommend Javascript and Node.js.  You can find an economy of scale in learning if you use Javascript for both front-end and back-end.  If you go with Javascript for your backend, then you will likely use node.js as your back-end execution execution engine.
4. **Back-end Framework.**  If you go with my node.js recommendation, then you'd want to use Express at your main web server framework and then probably use a templating engine.  Again, there are a zillion templating engines out there.  I use Handlebars.  Other popular engines to use with node.js are Jade, Dust, EJS.
5. **Back-end Database.**  Others can probably help you better than I on this one.  There's a lot written about the [MEAN stack](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and) which is MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node.js.  If you were going to just pick a popular combination that has been written about a lot and that obviously works well enough together for a lot of people to choose it and write about it, this would be done choice.  A more thoughtful database choice involves understanding your particular needs and aligning that with the type of database.

I'd probably suggest you start with the MEAN stack on the backend and generic web pages on the front-end and you can always change out the database later if you find MongoDB isn't a good match for what you're trying to do.

**Edit**

Based on your comments, here's a recommendation for a sequence of steps to get started:

**Step 1 - Get Node.js/Express server up and running**

1. Install, npm, node.js and Express on your local computer.
2. Get a basic web server up and running using Express that serves two separate web pages where each has a link between them so you can navigate from one to the other in a browser.
3. Connect your browser to localhost and verify you can run those web pages.

Even without much prior knowledge of Javascript, node.js or Express you should be able to get that up and running in a few hours barring any installation snafus.  There are plenty of step-by-step tutorials for getting this combination up and running that you should be good there.

**Step 2 - Collect Data from Web Form and Persist It**

1. Create a form in one of the web pages that your server serves.
2. Create a route in Express to handle the posting of data from that form.
3. When data from the form is sent to your server, handle that request, parse the data and write it to a flat file in your server

At this point, you now know how to get data from the front-end to the back-end.

**Step 3 - Create a View of Previously Persisted Data**

1. Create another web page and another Express route that you will populate with data that you have written to your flat file.
2. The browser will request a route.  That route will hit an Express route handler.  In that route handler, you will read data from your flat file and dynamically construct a web page that shows the data from the file.
3. While, you won't likely do it this manually in the long run (a database and templates will make life easier in the long run), this is the "crawl" stage in "crawl, walk, run" and cements your understanding of how request/response works.

**Step 4 - Now Start Designing your Real Application**

1. Figure out what type of data you really need stored and how you plan on doing that (you probably bring in a database here).
2. Figure out what types of views of that data you need to create (you probably bring in a template system here).
3. Figure out what actions you want to offer the viewers to add, modify, delete persisted data (start thinking about how you're going to surface the user interface to both the workers and the managers).
4. Figure out what type of authentication you need for your app.

Comment: I would also suggest adding React in the front-end framework as something to check out. See if OP likes it.

Comment: Browser-based is a given, here, so... JavaScript, HTML, CSS - done. Front-end framework - one of my books is about AngularJS, so - done. Back-End language - JavaScript on NodeJS - done. Express as backend framework - OK. Jade for templating? Will trust your advice that it is applicable here - done. Database - I should not have mentioned database, huh? I will research the term "MEAN stack". Coming from a (long ago) Lisp background, I would be happy with a flat file full of list objects, but there are surely better options now haha.

Comment: @HippoPotamus - I added some sequential steps you might follow.

Answer (score 3):

Although is this not a good question for StackOverflow, as it generates opinions, I will answer it. FreeCodeCamp.com is a great resource for learning how to develop web applications. It will take a long time (as it teaches you a lot about both front and back end development) but it seems like a good resource.

And it's free, so it's not like you are locked in after paying for a course.

After you feel you have a handle on that, write your back end and (just for pricing and availability sake) deploy to Heroku.

Good luck! Welcome to the wonderful world of web development.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did attempt to phrase the question in a non-opinion oriented way. I'm not asking for the best solution. I'm simply asking for ANY solution, because every resource I have looked at so far has been deeply flawed. A list of learning resources that work with modern components does not have to be opinion-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

> Does there exist a tutorial/college class/book/learning resource that puts all of the necessary components together so a person can have a list of the, say, 12 frameworks and 5 languages they need to learn in order to implement this kind of application?

I think definetely no, at least not all what you want. That's would be not true, because there are so many ways to build somethings and there is no one right for all.

1. If you want to build web application, you exactly have to start with HTML & CSS.(Jade is just HTML preprocessor).
2. Then you have to learn JavaScript, so you can take a look at the O'reilly books (with animal on the cover).
3. To not invent a bicycle you need to learn then JS framework. Most popular for now are: AnguarJS and ReactJS.(Personally I would recomend ReactJS)

*And JSON is just a JavaScript Object Notation - so if you know JS - then you know JSON :)
AJAX is a small part of JS.
jQuery is just a library to make a work with JS much simpler and resolve the browsers incompability.*

4.NodeJS is the same as JavaScript, but on the server(while JS is in browser). So if you know JS it would be easy to learn NodeJS.

**And ye, happy coding! :)**

Comment: I like your attitude. I hope to emulate it someday. I have been out of coding too long, and some of this new stuff frustrates me. JSON is just a.... AJAX is just a.... jQuery is just a... and yet they make my head hurt. So these are all just "make it better" constructs on top of JavaScript? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Not exactly, but yeah, something like that.
> I have been out of coding too long, and some of this new stuff frustrates me.
I understand you, but you don't have to be frustrated now. Just learn it sttep by step :)